# Filling blank space \hspace with \dotfill in \tabbing environment?

Tags: tabbing

How can I fill blank spaces with `\dotfill` in `\tabbing` environment? How can I adjust the length of `\dotfill`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace*{3cm}\=\hspace*{2cm}\= \kill
column1a \> column2a \> column3a \\
column1b \> column2b \> column3b 
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabbing]

Comment: Apparently, the cells’ contents are always boxed at their natural width; the space between cells in a row is added later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to replace `tabbing` by `tabular` or `longtable`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}p{3cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{2cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}<{\dotfill}@{}}
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
column1b & column2b & column3b 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

resp.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{}p{3cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{2cm}<{\dotfill}@{}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-5cm}@{}}
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
column1b & column2b & column3b 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I use this tabular of @Schweinebacke and change the last column to raggedleft?

Comment: @phasefieldguy Have you tried to add `>{\dotfill}` before the last column? `>{…}` and `<{…}` are documented in the [`array` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf).